# WhatsApp Web keeps disconnecting on one of my Wi-Fi's, why?

Tags: windows, networking, android, wifi-configuration, whatsapp

I moved to a new flat and got a new WiFi (Sky, UK).

The problem is that whenever I connect to WhatsApp Web or WhatsApp Desktop it only works for a minute or so then it disconnects. After a while (when I wake my phone), it will come back on, again only for a minute or so.

I have already tried different approaches like below: https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/16200/whatsapp-web-keeps-disconnecting

Specifically, I already tried:

- setting the app to always run in the background
- setting to not optimize the battery
- reinstalling WhatsApp

But the approaches don't work. The problem doesn't happen on other wifi's. For example, it works perfectly on a different wifi (same computer, same phone).

Clearly not a phone or laptop problem!!!

Please help me out.

Comment: while using this network connection, have you encountered any other connection issues? Or just this application? Have you ever tried to reinstall the network drive and update it?

Comment: There are no other problems that I noticed. However, I can say that this problem happens for anyone (on any phone/laptop) who tries to use what's app web.